# sas curl login to a secured dynamic website

Tags: curl, sas

New to the forum. I'm wondering if anyone knows how Curl handles dynamic page using SAS. For instance, I tried to use similar code below to curl following dynamic page in Base SAS: https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=123  and the result shows 'objId' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  program or batch file. Anyone has any ideas ? Thanks in Advance.

```
%let a = ll;
%let b = 1117016710;
data _null_;
  call symput ('curl_cmd', "&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a^%nrstr(&objId=)&b ");
run;

filename curl pipe "&curl_cmd" lrecl=32767;
data tmp;
  length xml $&maxchars;
  infile curl truncover end=eof;
  input @1 xml $&maxchars..; 
  if lengthn(xml) ge &maxchars then do;      
    put "ERROR: FAILED FOR process BECAUSE XML WAS > &maxchars CHARS";
    put "OBSERVATION: " _n_;
    put xml;
    stop;
  end;
run;
filename curl clear;

the results shows:
filename curl pipe "&curl_cmd" lrecl=32767;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OBJID not resolved.

 PROCESS=C:\test\curl\curl.exe -k -u user:pwd
      https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll^&objId=1117016710,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767

Stderr output:
   Total     Received  Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0
   0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
NOTE: 0 records were read from the infile CURL.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TMP has 0 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.35 seconds
```

After Joe's suggestion, I made a few changes, here is the results below:

```
%let curl_executable = C:\test\curl\curl.exe;
%let maxchars        = 3000;
%let userpass        = user:pwd;

%let a = ll;
%let b = 1117016710;
%let curl_cmd=&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a.%nrstr(&objId)=&b ;
%put &=curl_cmd;

data _null_;
  call symput ('curl_cmd', '&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a.%nrstr(&objId)=&b');
run;
%put &=curl_cmd;

filename curl pipe "&curl_cmd" lrecl=32767;
data tmp;
  length xml $&maxchars;

  infile curl truncover end=eof;
  input @1 xml $&maxchars..;

  if lengthn(xml) ge &maxchars then do;      
    put "ERROR: FAILED FOR process BECAUSE XML WAS > &maxchars CHARS";
    put "OBSERVATION: " _n_;
    put xml;
    stop;
  end;
run;
filename curl clear;
```

The results log file returns:

```
37   %let curl_executable = C:\test\curl\curl.exe;
38   %let maxchars        = 3000;
39   %let userpass        = user:pwd;
40   %let a = ll;
41   %let b = 1117016710;
42   %let curl_cmd=&curl_executable -k -u &userpass
42 ! %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a.%nrstr(&objId)=&b
42 ! ;
43   %put &=curl_cmd;
CURL_CMD=C:\test\curl\curl.exe -k -u user:pwd
https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=1117016710
44
45   data _null_;
46     call symput ('curl_cmd', '&curl_executable -k -u &userpass
46 ! %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a.%nrstr(&objId)=&b'
46 ! );
47   run;

NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


48   %put &=curl_cmd;
CURL_CMD=C:\test\curl\curl.exe -k -u user:pwd
https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=1117016710
49
50   filename curl pipe "&curl_cmd" lrecl=32767;
51   data tmp;
52     length xml $&maxchars;
53
54     infile curl truncover end=eof;
55     input @1 xml $&maxchars..;
56
57     if lengthn(xml) ge &maxchars then do;
58       put "ERROR: FAILED FOR process BECAUSE XML WAS > &maxchars CHARS";
59       put "OBSERVATION: " _n_;
60       put xml;
61       stop;
62     end;
63   run;

NOTE: The infile CURL is:
      Unnamed Pipe Access Device,

      PROCESS=C:\test\curl\curl.exe -k -u user:pwd
      https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=1117016710,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767

Stderr output:
   Total     Received  Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0
   0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
'objId' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NOTE: 0 records were read from the infile CURL.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TMP has 0 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.43 seconds
      cpu time            0.04 seconds


64   filename curl clear;
NOTE: Fileref CURL has been deassigned.
65
66
67   proc print data=tmp;
68   run;

NOTE: No observations in data set WORK.TMP.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is test the string output by PROCESS.  Copy/paste everything from after = to before the comma.  Execute it at the command line.  If that works, then you have some issue getting that properly to the command processor; if that doesn't work, fix it so it does work, then change your SAS so that macro variable matches that.

Answer (score 0):

The warning about the macro OBJID not recognized is annoying but it is not the problem.  That is simply saying that &OBJID in the URL is not resolving.  That's OK, you want &OBJID.

I suspect your problem is the `^` character in the URL.  I suspect you need a `.` in its place to delineate the `&a` macro variable.

Do you really want the url to be mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=ll ^ &objId=1117016710? (Added spaces to help it stand out)

Comment: Hi DomPazz, Thanks for your quick feedback. I tried link without ^ before: %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a.%nrstr(&objId=)&b ");  
and it still giving me 0 records and same warning about objId. It only behaves like this for dynamic page.

Comment: ^ will end the macro variable, so that's not the problem (unless ^ is an accident).  That said, the initial question suggests it's not appropriate, so I'm confused why it's there.

Answer (score 0):

This might help simplify the error checking if it doesn't actually solve your problem:

Use %let to define a macro variable, not CALL SYMPUT, unless you have a good reason to do the latter. In this case since you're using macro variables as components, you probably don't have a good reason to.

```
%let a = ll;
%let b = 1117016710;
%let curl_executable=c:\curl.exe;
%let userpass=password;

%let curl_cmd=&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a%nrstr(&objId=)&b ;
%put &=curl_cmd;
```

Second, to avoid the warning if you DO use call symput, you can put it in single quotes.  Don't worry, the &s will still get resolved when it's actually used.

```
data _null_;
  call symput ('curl_cmd', '&curl_executable -k -u &userpass %nrstr(https://mysite.com/kl/livelink.exe?func=)&a%nrstr(&objId=)&b');
run;
%put &=curl_cmd;
```

(Side note: &= only works on 9.3+, so if you have 9.2, remove the = )

Comment: I edited my post for you to read the log file. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.